# Numerical integration producing messages Integrate::slwcon and Integrate::agpginf

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to evaluate an integral numerically. Here is my code:

[image]

It produces error messages:

[image]

How can I solve this integral?

Comment: It would be difficult to help you unless you provide your code in `InputForm[]` and paste it here.

Comment: You are using `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision` wrong. The latter has to be larger than the former. With `WorkingPrecision ->MachinePrecision` you will get results faster.

Comment: Before trying to make a table of integrals, get the integration working for just  one value of `M` and `a`. Remove the options `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision`. They are not helping you.

Comment: I'm now curious about those integration limits; are they actually finite, or are they supposed to be infinite limits?

Comment: Sir I have tried evaluating the integral for one value of a and M .But I am still getting the same error message. But I got a value even after showing the error message  @m_goldberg